# Copy all the data from one user control to another user control of Same Type

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I want to transfer all data from HomeAddressUC to PermanentAddressUC with checkBox SameAsPrevious

Each UserControl has same Type(AddressUserControl)

[image]

DataSource to Fill HomeAddressUC is code is like this

```
private void SetTabPageDetails(string tabPageName, CustomerDetails customerDetailsCache)
{
     customerDetailsCache = // calling stored procedure
     PermanentAddressUC.SetDetails(customerDetailsCache.Addresses[0]);
}
```

Scope of that DataSource is upto it method `SetTabPageDetails()` only 
logic I was trying to implement is on checkbox changed event is

```
if (chkSameAsPervious.Checked)
{
    foreach (var addressCtl in from Control ctl in this.ADDRESS_TAB.Controls select ctl as BankSys24.UI.UserControls.AddressUserControl)
    {
        if (addressCtl.GroupBoxText == "Mailing Address")
        {
            // want to do something here
        }
    }
}
```

I try to follow the relevant link

[Best practice when you need two user controls (winforms) to communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063010/best-practice-when-you-need-two-user-controls-winforms-to-communicate?rq=1)

it says to use the Third Common User Control a Container or interface

What is the optimized way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to different user controls for home and mailing address if all the fields same?

you can use one user control for both and create property for set the group name as "Home address" or "Mailing address"

You can have two public methods to set address fields by passing address object and get address object by reading fields of the form.

On check change event of the checkbox you can get address object by calling home address user control instant get address method and then you can set that details on mailing address user control instant by calling set address method by passing address object.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Shortest Solution I Found is like this :

```
if (chkSameAsPervious.Checked)
            {
                    MailingAddressUC.SetDetails(PermanentAddressUC.GetDetails() as BankSys24.DTO.Customer.Address);
            }
```

where

```
 public object GetDetails()
        {
            return new BankSys24.DTO.Customer.Address { //data };
        }
```

and

```
  public void SetDetails(object input)
        {
           //intermediate Object
            if (details != null)
            {
//Mapping

}
```

Getdetails maps the all data as Container Class Object which can be Directly pass to SetDetails() ...